# Difference betwen "if" sentences with different { structure

Tags: c, if-statement

What is the difference between the following sentences.

```
if (i1)
   if (i2) s1;
else s2;
```

and

```
if (i1)
{  
   if (i2) s1;
   else s2;
}
```

and

```
if (i1)
 {
  if (i2) s1;
 }
else s2;
```

Comment: Why don't you test it? And **always** use braces. Doing so will result in better readability and less chance of errors.

Comment: By braces you mean { and  }? Sory my english is bad. Also Ed, this wasnt homework it is from a book i am reading.

Comment: If it is from a book the answer would be in the preceding chapter or at the back

Comment: My motto is "always use braces, you do not want to get caught with your trousers down"

Comment: Nah it isnt it only shows different posibiliys

Comment: But when do you use breces. After if or what. Do you have a link to some website that explains that weel

Comment: what are the differences in output if you try printing something for `s2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code fragment is badly indented, it should read:

```
if (i1)
   if (i2)
       s1;
   else
       s2;
```

Which is equivalent to your second fragment, but obviously very different from the third fragment:

```
if (i1) {
   if (i2)
       s1;
} else {
   s2;
}
```

This issue is called the **dangling else** problem.  You can avoid it completely by always using curly braces `{` and `}` around blocks commanded by `if`.  You would write the first and second fragments as:

```
if (i1) {
   if (i2) {
       s1;
   } else {
       s2;
   }
}
```

and the third as

```
if (i1) {
   if (i2) {
       s1;
   }
} else {
   s2;
}
```

Wikipedia has an article about this very issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else

Comment: Do you know any website links that explain that well?

Comment: Is second example, why didnt you use braces after a second if?

Comment: @ŽigaGazvoda: my intent was to reproduce your fragments, just changing the indentation.  I clarified the answer.